# Simple program to shift a set of coplanar points not working

Tags: c++, math, vector-graphics

I am calculating a set of shifted points for a set of original points using simple cross products. Later i compare to see if the resulting set of vectors are parallel. I see that the comparison test fails for almost all cases. Can someone please tell me why?

```
// Here osg::Vec3 is a container for three floats
std::vector<osg::Vec3 > originalPoints;
originalPoints.push_back(osg::Vec3(10.0,11.0,13.0));
originalPoints.push_back(osg::Vec3(-10.0,12.0,13.0));
originalPoints.push_back(osg::Vec3(5.0,6.0,13.0));
originalPoints.push_back(osg::Vec3(6.75,11.0,13.0));
originalPoints.push_back(osg::Vec3(8.6,-11.0,13.0));

// Here the "^" operator represents cross product   
osg::Vec3 tileUpVec = originalPoints[0]^originalPoints[1];
tileUpVec.normalize(); 

std::vector<osg::Vec3> shift;

osg::Vec3 lineVec1, lineVec2. resultVec;
lineVec1  = originalPoints[0] - originalPoints[1];
resultVec = lineVec1 ^ tileUpVec;
resultVec.normalise();
shift.push_back(resultVec);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < originalPoints.size(); i++)
{
  lineVec1 = originalPoints[i-1] - originalPoints[i];
  lineVec2 = originalPoints[i] - originalPoints[i+1];
  resultVec = (lineVec + lineVec2) ^ tileUpVec;
  resultVec.normalise();
  shift.push_back(resultVec);
}

lineVec1  = originalPoints[i-1] - originalPoints[i];
resultVec = lineVec1 ^ tileUpVec;
resultVec.normalise();
shift.push_back(resultVec);

ASSERT_TRUE(shift.size() == originalPoints.size());

std::vector<osg::Vec3> shiftedPoints;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < shift.size(); i++)
{
  shiftedPoints.push_back((shift[i]+originalPoints[i])); 
}

float result;

// Here "*" operator represnts dot product
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < (originalPoints.size() - 1); j++)
{
  lineVec1 = shiftedPoints[j] - shiftedPoints[j+1];
  lineVec1.normalize();
  lineVec2 = originalPoints[j] - originalPoints[j+1];
  lineVec2.normalize();
  result = lineVec1 * lineVec2;
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  EXPECT_TRUE(result > 0.995);
}
```

The EXPECT_TRUE always fails. And this means they are not parallel. Whats the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a vector full of shifts which are all different. When you shift the points in the old collection by a bunch of different shift vectors, you should not expect the vectors between the new points and the old to be the same. (If there's some math you've done that you think guarantees they will be, you should include that in your question so we can check it.)

If you're confident the math is right and that the issue is with the code, you do seem to have a bounds error in the first iteration of your for loop. It looks for `originalPoints[-1]`.

Edited to add:

Inside your first for loop, you define

`linevec1 = original_points[i-1] - original_points[i]
 linevec2 = original_points[i] - original_points[i+1]`

then you only use `linevec1+linevec2`, so why not just say

`linevec = original_points[i-1]-original_points[i+1]`?

Comment: Yes, agreed about both the points. I fixed the loop. Also i ensured parallel vectors by also considering magnitudes. Suppose 3 vectors a,b and c are such that ab and bc make 90 degree angle, then if a and c are shifted by 1 unit, b should be shifted by sqrt(2) units. This works well for a set of points which is all coplanar. But suppose the set of points are not coplanar, then i need to find the tileUPVec for the set of 3 points in the loop. Can you please tell me how to calculate this?